# When does JavaScript use `two's complement` format?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754, twos-complement

Two's complement is used to represent signed integers, however 64bit IEEE754 float can also represent signed integers. Since the latter is the format in which JavaScript stores its numbers, I'm wondering whether two's complement is used at all in JavaScript and if so in what situations?

Comment: Does all Javascript engines always store numbers as floating point numbers?

Comment: Long answer: when doing bitwise operations on said numbers.

Comment: @EdHeal not if you use asm.js in an engine that supports asm.js

Comment: @JanDvorak - It was a rhetorical question

Comment: @EdHeal, well, that's what is defined by the ECMAScript standard

Comment: @JanDvorak, what are `said numbers`?

Comment: @Maximus - assuming all Javascript engines conform to said standard

Comment: @EdHeal, well, in my question I assume those engines that conform :)

Comment: @EdHeal Well obviously if the JavaScript engine doesn't conform to the standard, then nothing can be said about it, so there's no point letting them enter the discussion. A nonconforming JavaScript engine could print "meow!" when you add two integers, or it could decide to parse your program as a Python program.

Comment: @RaymondChen - It history has told us about web browsers in the past that standards get interpreted in different ways. See IE vs Firefox and the tricks required to get a page to work for both

Comment: @EdHeal Interpreting the standard differently is different from not conforming to the standard at all. (It's also different from "attempting to conform to the standard and falling short due to a bug.") As written, the original question was about JavaScript the language, not JavaScript implementations.